# How to update a Bound JTable via code

Tags: java, netbeans, data-binding, netbeans-platform

I have a JTable bound with my database using Netbeans Wizard. Everything works fine but when I try to change the query and results based on filtering the table stops displaying the new results.

```
    private static void updateResults() {
        if (complaintList != null) {
            LOG.log(Level.FINE, getQuery());
            complaintList.clear();
            complaintQuery = entityManager.createQuery(getQuery())
                    .setMaxResults(1000);
            complaintList = complaintQuery.getResultList();
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Result size: {0}", complaintList.size());
            complaints.firePropertyChange(null, true, false);
        }
    }
```

Where:

- complaintList is the list containing the results which is bound to the table.
- complaintQuery is the bound Query.

I verified that the result has a size > 0. The contents of the table only update when I click/move one of the scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be pretty, but made it work by selecting the last row on the table after the change.

```
if (!complaintList.isEmpty()) {
   complaints.changeSelection(complaintList.size() - 1, 0,
              false, false);
}
```